# Apache Ignite: what is atomic_cache_delete_history?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

What is atomic_cache_delete_history?
Why it produces so much memory traffic (minor GC every 5 sec)?

Answer (score 0):

atomic_cache_delete_history - is a queue of entries awaiting for deletion. It is a part of deferred deletion mechanism. Queue is cleaning on partition eviction that can be caused by e.g. cache destroy or rebalancing.

By default, queue max size is 200_000 entries for every cache.

You can try to reduce queue size with IGNITE_ATOMIC_CACHE_DELETE_HISTORY_SIZE system property.